# Php mysql Query not working posting errors

Tags: php, mysql

My php mysql query isn't working or at least thats what I assume. If you guys could maybe notice something I am not seeing it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here are the errors I am receiving:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\
Fatal error: Call to a member function free() on a non-object in D:\
```

I have 9 columns with varchar:

```
Part Number,Alternate Partnumber,Qty,
Description,Part Condition Code,Price,
Location,Barcode,Consignment
```

I have created a search bar and I want customers to be able to enter in a part number and it finds that part number and all of the info on its row.

I am using *Php and Mysql Web Development* by Luke Welling and Laura Thomson
So I am using part of they're code from a chapter.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    //create short variable names
    $searchtype = "Part Number";
    $searchterm = $_POST['searchterm'];

    //echo "$searchtype";
    //echo "$searchterm";

    if(!$searchtype || !$searchterm)
    {
        echo 'You must enter a part number please try again';
        exit;
    }

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $searchtype = addslashes($searchtype);
        $searchterm = addslashes($searchterm);
    }

    @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'partstest');

    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo 'Error: Could not connect to database. Please try again later.';
        exit;
    }

    //$query = "SELECT $searchterm * FROM inventory WHERE Part Number";
    $query = "select * from inventory where " .$searchtype. " like '%".$searchterm."%'";


    $result = $db->query($query);
    //$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $num_results = $result->num_rows;
    //$num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    echo "<p>Number of books found: ".$num_results."</p>";

    for($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++)
    {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        //$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo "<p><strong>".($i+1).". Part Number: ";
        echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['Part Number']));
        echo "</strong><br /> Alternate Part Number: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['Alternate Part Number']);
        echo "<br />Qty: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['Qty']);
        echo "<br />Description: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['Description']);
        echo "<br />Part Condition: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['Part Condition']);
        echo "<br />Price: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['Price']);
        echo "<br />Location: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['Location']);
        echo "<br />Barcode: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['Barcode']);
        echo "<br />Consignment: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['Consignment']);
        echo "</p>";

    }

    $result->free();
    //mysqli_free_result($result);
    $db->close();

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please post the output of the following code:

```
var_dump(get_object_vars($result));
```

Seems your $db is empty due to misplaced @

Comment: I got rid of the @, and still getting errors.

I did the var_dump(get_object_vars($result));

here are results

Warning: get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, boolean given in D:\xampp\ on line 40
NULL 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\ on line 42
Number of books found:


Fatal error: Call to a member function free() on a non-object in D:\xampp on line 73

Comment: after you removed the @ can you please post results of: var_dump(get_object_vars($db)); Are you sure you are giving mysqli all the correct __construct flags?

Comment: here is the output after that. For some reason its not creating a object from the query.




Warning: get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, boolean given in D:\xampp\htdocs\WA\searchResult1.php on line 41
NULL 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\WA\searchResult1.php on line 43
Number of books found:


Fatal error: Call to a member function free() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\WA\searchResult1.php on line 74

Comment: It is not an issue with your query, it is an issue with initializing $db as a mysqli. I assume this is an include inside of another larger project that has mysqli defined? If not then you might want to include() it. If not, you may have a class problem...

Comment: Ok when I do this: 
$query = "SELECT * FROM `inventory` LIMIT 0, 30 ";
It prints my list correctly.

But when I try this:
$query = "SELECT * FROM `inventory` WHERE 'Part Number' like '412-330-437-103'";

It finds 0 results, and that is a correct part number, I have even tried others. 

Is there any other way that I could change that, I am pretty sure that's not correct.

Comment: Fixed it! For some reason sum_result was always 0, I added another line and did sum_result +=1 and then it started working, but displaying 2 results even though it was only finding 1. Then I commented it out and it worked perfectly. So kinda weird but not sure why that fixed it.

Comment: you shouldnt name your column's with a space. but im glad you got it rigged and working :) the query SHOULD look something like:  $query = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE part_number LIKE '%412-330-437-103%'"

Answer (score 0):

Your "$db"-object seems to be empty because you wrote this:

```
@ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'partstest');
```

but the @ is wrong here, also you should look at the error [php-doc](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php) and do some "echo" of your objects, to look if they are false or null